# Php array to formatted Text Key : Value

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

I have this array:

```
Array ( [location] => Array ( [country] => India [country_code] => IN [region] => [region_code] => [city] => [zip] => [latitude] => 13.044468 [longitude] => 77.575665 [ip_address] => 123.236.219.154 [timestamp] => 1317496122 [route] => 3rd Cross Rd [neighborhood] => Basaveshwara Layout [sublocality] => BCITS PVT LTD [locality] => Bengaluru [administrative_area_level_2] => Bengaluru Rural [administrative_area_level_1] => Karnataka ) )
```

I wonder if there is a way that I can format it some what like this:

```
country: India
country_code:In
```

That is like 
`Key : Value`, 
`Key : Value`, 
`Key : Value`

Comment: do you mean format the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that?

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
  echo $key." : ".$value.",";
}
```

You have to check the last value and remove the "," then.

Comment: You can remove the trailing comma with: `substr($output, 0, -1)` (of course you need to concat all output to a var before echo'ing).